# Spacing in list with math environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, environments, enumerate, line-spacing

Check out the following example. I would like to write the code as in the second list, but get output equivalent to the other two. However, there is a lot of extra vertical space after the third item of the second list, and I don't know why, or what to do about it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{listitem}{\item}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\item
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\item
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\[
    2 + 2 = 4
\]

\item
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\end{enumerate}

\hrule

\begin{enumerate}

\begin{listitem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{listitem}

\begin{listitem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{listitem}

\begin{listitem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\[
    2 + 2 = 4
\]
\end{listitem}

\begin{listitem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{listitem}

\end{enumerate}

\hrule

\begin{enumerate}

\begin{listitem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{listitem}

\begin{listitem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{listitem}

\begin{listitem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\[
    2 + 2 = 4
\]
\end{listitem}
%
\begin{listitem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{listitem}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that you left the second argument of the `\newenvironment` empty:

```
\newenvironment{listitem}{\item}{}
```

If you add `\ignorespacesafterend` as a second argument all extra space at the end of your environment is ignored.

```
\newenvironment{listitem}{\item}{\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Comment: You are enlightened ;) +1

Comment: @HarishKumar Very kind :-)